# Unable to get COUNTIF in vba function working

Tags: excel, vba, countif

Can someone shed some light on why the countif statement below fails ? I can see in the debugger that the range "CountRange" has a value in row 90 of "COL0117".

I am using the countif to avoid doing the vlookup and getting an error. If count = 0 then don't bother running the vlookup

```
Function LookupExternalData( _
    ByVal FilePath As String, _
    ByVal ProjectID As String, _
    ByVal ColumnNumber As Long) _
As Variant
    Const ProcName As String = "LookupExternalData"
    ' On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Const WorksheetName As String = "PPM Data extract"
    Const ColumnsAddress As String = "A1:CD1000"
    
    Dim objXL
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim count As Double
    Dim LookupRange As Range
    Dim CountRange As Range
    
    
    Set objXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    objXL.Visible = True
    Set wb = objXL.Workbooks.Open(FilePath, 0, True)
    
    With wb
        
        With .Worksheets(WorksheetName)
            ' Set LookupRange = Intersect(.Range(ColumnsAddress), wb.Worksheets(WorksheetName).UsedRange)
            Set LookupRange = .Range(ColumnsAddress)
                
            On Error Resume Next
            count = 100
            Set CountRange = .Range("A:A")
            
            count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(CountRange, "COL0117")

            LookupExternalData = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ProjectID, LookupRange, ColumnNumber, False)
            
        End With
        
SafeExit:
        On Error Resume Next ' if file path error
            .Close SaveChanges:=False
            objXL.Quit
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume SafeExit
End Function
```

Comment: First you can't get an error because `On Error Resume Next` hides all error messages. Also there is no use of `count` in this function at all. Please be more precise about what exactly goes wrong and in which line.

Comment: Running the CountIf is probably slower than just running the VLookup.  If you drop the `WorksheetFunction` then a non-match with vlookup won't throw a runtime error and you can test the return value using `IsError()`

Comment: I tried to use is error but it also terminated the function and returned an error. Would you be able to show me the syntax in case I have written it incorrectly? Is the variable count a protected term in VBA ?

Comment: Are you calling this function from VBA, or from a worksheet cell?   Why are you creating a separate Excel object if you're already working in excel?

Comment: Hi Tom, I am calling this from a VBA function. I need to check if the vlokkup fails. I train iserror and could not get it to work. The countif is intended to check if the vlokkup will fail and then exit the function

Answer (score 0):

Simplified to show the basic approach:

```vb
Sub tester()
    Debug.Print LookupExternalData("C:\Temp\SO2\blah.xlsx", "Project0008", 4)
End Sub



Function LookupExternalData(ByVal FilePath As String, ByVal ProjectID As String, _
                                               ByVal ColumnNumber As Long) As Variant
    
    Const WorksheetName As String = "PPM Data extract"
    Const ColumnsAddress As String = "A1:CD1000"
    
    Dim objXL, wb As Workbook, res
    
    Set objXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    objXL.Visible = True
    Set wb = objXL.Workbooks.Open(FilePath, 0, True)
    
    'without `WorksheetFunction` no run-time error is raised
    '   in the event there's no match: test the return value instead
    res = Application.VLookup(ProjectID, _
                   wb.Worksheets(WorksheetName).Range(ColumnsAddress), _
                   ColumnNumber, False)
    ' `res` will be an error value if no match was made
    LookupExternalData = IIf(IsError(res), "???", res) 'edit as appropriate
    wb.Close savechanges:=False
    objXL.Quit
End Function
```